# 例外処理をした後プログラムが停止してしまう

Tags: c++

例外処理をした後プログラムが停止してしまいます。

具体的には `try{}catch{}` で何も入っていない連結リスト（連結リストのヘッド、先頭が `nullptr` を指している状態）から先頭に入っている値を取ろうとした場合を想定した例外処理でして、そこでプログラムが正常に終わるはずだったのですが、以下のメッセージがスクリーンに表示されプログラムが停止してしまいます。

```
lab9.exeは動作を停止しました。問題が発生したため、プログラムが正しく動作しなくなりました。
プログラムは閉じられ、解決策がある場合はWindowsから通知されます。
```

いつもなら、指示を完了した後（今回の場合「List error saying no link in the list」を表示する指示）、「Process finished with exit code 0」と表示されプログラムが終了するのですが、このプログラムは「Process finished with exit code 0」が表示されずに停止してしまいます。
これは例外処理でしてもこうなってしまうものなのでしょうか。

#### 現状のソースコード

List.h

```
#ifndef LAB9_LIST_H
#define LAB9_LIST_H

#include <string>
#include<exception>
using std::string;

class list_error : public std::exception{
private:
    string errorMessage;
public:
    list_error(string errorMessage = "") : errorMessage(errorMessage){}
    virtual ~list_error(){}
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return errorMessage.c_str();
    }

};

template <typename T>
class Link
{
private:
    T value;
    Link* next;
public:
    //constructor
    Link(T value, Link* next = nullptr): value(value), next(next){}
    //destructor
    virtual ~Link(){}
    //return value
    T getValue() const {return this->value;}
    //return next
    Link* getNext() const{return this->next;}
    //set next
    void setNext(Link* next){this->next = next;}
};



template <typename T>
class List
{
private:
    Link<T>* head;


public:
    List():head(nullptr){}


    T getHead()
    {
        //throw exception
        if(head == nullptr)
        {
            throw list_error("no link in the list");
        }
        return head->getValue();
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{

    List<int> intList;

    // testing Exception
    try{
        cout << intList.getHead() << endl;
        cout << "Should have thrown an exception." << endl;
    }
    catch(list_error &ex){
        cout << "List error saying " << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    catch( ... ) {
        cout << "Caught something else" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 使っているOS,コンパイラ,コンパイル時オプション等は何でしょう？ それからエラーメッセージは略さずに表示されたままを過不足無く提示してください。ちなみにWindowsのVC++だと`list_error`クラスの定義を`list`クラスの前に移動しないとコンパイルエラーになりました。

Comment: `List.h` の最初(`using std::string;`の直後)に forward declaration(前方宣言) を入れる必要があるかと思います。`class list_error;`  参考までに、`Ubuntu Linux 20.10/g++ 10.2.0` でコンパイル・実行してみましたが正常終了します。

Comment: 使っているOSはWindows10、コンパイラはCLion、コンパイル時のオプションは知識不足で何を指しているのかわかりませんでした。エラー状況を上記に足しました。簡単に略すと、いつもは指示をすべて完了した後、「Process finished with exit code 0」と表示されプログラムが終了するのですが、このプログラムは「Process finished with exit code 0」が表示されずに停止してしまいます。これはコンパイルエラーに含まれるのでしょうか。

Comment: そして、上記のようにlist_errorクラスをlistクラスの前に持ってきましたが、まったく同じエラーが発生してしました。ほかに考えられる問題はありますでしょうか。

Comment: それはマイナーな環境でしょうから、助言や回答は難しいかもしれません。例えばCLionのデバッグ環境特有の現象かもしれませんし。[実行とデバッグ](https://www.jetbrains.com/ja-jp/clion/features/run-and-debug.html) 今CLionを使える人が調べて何か反応してくれるのを待ちましょう。

Comment: エラーメッセージ「動作を停止しました。……」から察するに、[「アプリケーション(.exe)は動作を停止しました」が出る原因と対処法 – Windows10](https://itojisan.xyz/trouble/16576/#7)が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 動作停止の対処法を記事を見ていろいろ試してみましたがうまくいきませんでした。Clionに詳しい方が反応してみるを待ってみます。いろいろ調べていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: `string errorMessage;` でなくて文字列リテラル＋ポインタつまり  `const char* errorMessage;` を使ってみたらどうなるか試してみる価値はあるかもしれないっス（例外処理ハンドラの中は `noexcept` でないとまずいのに `clion` の `basic_string` の実装がそうなってないかもしれない）

Comment: なるほどと思いながら、string errorMeassage を const char* errorMessageに変えてコードしなおしてみましたが、動作が停止して、正しく終了しませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

質問されてからしばらく経っているので、もうどうでもよくなってるかも知れませんが。

だいたい動きそうに見えますが、list_errorのコンストラクタ引数 errorMessage がメンバ変数 errorMessage と全く同じなのが気になります。

もしも、errorMessage(errorMessage) という書き方で、メンバ変数のコピーコンストラクタが呼ばれ、その引数に、メンバ変数自体が渡された場合、未初期化のstringオブジェクトをコピー元としてコピーコンストラクト処理を試み、その途中で不正番地参照か何かを起こしてずっこけることは考えられると思います。

コンストラクタ引数の名前をメンバ変数とずらしてみてはいかがでしょう。

コンストラクタ引数として、メンバ変数と同名のものを渡したくなるのは、よくあることなので、メンバ変数またはコンストラクタ引数のどちらかに、目印となるようなプレフィクスないしサフィックスをつけることが、C++では昔からよくやられると思います。例えば、メンバ変数の末尾に "_" をつけるルールとする、とかです。